# R: Delete rows based on a value in a selection of columns meeting a certain condition

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I would like to delete rows in a data frame if a value in a selection of columns occurs twice (or more). Here is an example:

```
set.seed(8)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:15), 15, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
show(dat)

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  7 10  5 10  7
2  4  5 14  7  9
3 12 11 12  2  3
```

I now want to delete rows in which the value 10 occurs twice (or more) in columns 1:4. This is what I tried:

```
myFunction <- function(x){
              ifelse(rowSums(x == 10) > 1, x, NULL)
              }

dat <- t(apply(dat[,1:4], 1, myFunction))
```

This returns me an error. I also tried using `subset()` in `myFunction`but I failed. The result should look like this:

```
> show(dat)          # <- Notice that row 1 was deleted because the value 10 occured twice

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
2  4  5 14  7  9
3 12 11 12  2  3
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You can just do `dat[rowSums(dat == 10) < 2,]`. But it seems you already had a working solution. What is your question exactly? And why are you keep using `show`?

Comment: Do you want to remove only rows where 10 occurs twice, or any rows where the same value occurs twice?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I only want to apply the function on columns 1:4, not on all 5 columns.

Comment: @TejaK I want to remove rows where the exact value 10 occurs twice.

Comment: `dat[rowSums(dat[-5] == 10) < 2,]` then?

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes, thank you. How would I write this with a function?

Comment: Something like `f <- function(x, n, cols) x[rowSums(x[cols] == n) < 2, ] ; f(dat, 10, -5)` maybe. This way you could apply this for different values/columns too.

Comment: @DavidArenburg this works, thank you.